# What is the Best way to define Adam Optimizer in PyTorch?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

For most PyTorch codes we use the following definition of Adam optimizer,

```
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=cfg['lr'], weight_decay=cfg['weight_decay'])
```

However, after repeated trials, I found that the following definition of Adam gives 1.5 dB higher PSNR which is huge.

```
optim = torch.optim.Adam(
            [
                {'params': get_parameters(model, bias=False)},
                {'params': get_parameters(model, bias=True), 'lr': cfg['lr'] * 2, 'weight_decay': 0},
            ],
            lr=cfg['lr'],
            weight_decay=cfg['weight_decay'])
```

The [Model](https://github.com/cydonia999/Learning_to_See_in_the_Dark_PyTorch/blob/470a6a8e9c6367d8fa88ee6d1dea211dd9fb1f81/models/lsid.py#L45) is a usual U-net with parameters defined in `init` and `forward action` as in any other PyTorch model.

The [get_parameters](https://github.com/cydonia999/Learning_to_See_in_the_Dark_PyTorch/blob/470a6a8e9c6367d8fa88ee6d1dea211dd9fb1f81/demo.py#L29) is defined as below.

```
def get_parameters(model, bias=False):
    for k, m in model._modules.items():
        print("get_parameters", k, type(m), type(m).__name__, bias)
        if bias:
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                yield m.bias
        else:
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, nn.ConvTranspose2d):
                yield m.weight
```

Could someone explain why the latter definition is better than the previous one?

Comment: The 2 definitions are different. The 2nd one gives double the LR for bias parameters while 1st one gives same LR for all parameters. The reason for improvement in the 2nd case may not be intuitively easy to identify. It is probably a better tuning of Adam for your setting (of dataset and network choice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second method, different configurations are being provided to update weights and biases. This is being done using [per-parameter options](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/optim.html) for the optimizer.

```
optim = torch.optim.Adam(
            [
                {'params': get_parameters(model, bias=False)},
                {'params': get_parameters(model, bias=True), 'lr': cfg['lr'] * 2, 'weight_decay': 0},
            ],
            lr=cfg['lr'],
            weight_decay=cfg['weight_decay'])
```

As per this, the learning rate for biases is 2 times that of weights, and weight decay is 0.

Now, the reason why it's being done could be the network not learning properly. Read more [Why is the learning rate for the bias usually twice as large as the the LR for the weights?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/23549/30543)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and resources. Is the `get_parameter` general enough, i.e will work for any NN? Can you please also explain this function in a line or two? Will, it be better to use `model.parameters()` instead of `model._modules.items()`?

Comment: yes, it's quite generic. you could use `parameters()`, but I think, here is a check on layer type as well. Working --> iterate over [modules](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/module-children-vs-module-modules/4551), then check which type of layer instance it is (e.g. conv), also, if `bias=True` in function argument, return bias, else weight. Hope it's clear.